# Verify Mobile payment Using Curl (SinglePayment)

Tags: php, android, json, paypal, android-volley

I have successfully integrate the PayPal into android app and get the payment id using sandbox account. Please tell me how to use the curl GET to verify the mobile payment.This is the curl but i dont know how to use it in php to get the response.

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXXXXXXXX \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer accessToken"
```

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

Answer (score 1):

php provide a lot of built-in functions to execute shell commands.

to execute your command , you only need to use one of the following functions: [exec](http://php.net/shell_exec), [shell_exec](http://php.net/exec), [system](http://php.net/system), or [one of these functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php).

```
$command = 'curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer accessToken"'

exec($command, $return);
```

another option is to using [`cURL`](http://php.net/curl) library:

here is a quick example, *you may have to customize this example by adding required curl opt_* options*

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer accessToken'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: @hassan I am getting following result PERMISSION_DENIED, how to soluve this?
 {"name":"PERMISSION_DENIED","message":"No permission for the requested operation","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"8ab402e2b3366"}